Client --> AWS ALB --> AWS Lambda: connection lost somewhere, how to identify?

The client made an API request.


Client --> ALB --> Lambda


Lambda worked fine with a response. Lambda duration is only about 3 seconds.

The client encountered timeout at 15th second.

The ALB log has this abnormal values:



elb_status_code: 460
target_processing_time: -1
response_processing_time: -1

I would like to know which part of the connection got closed. I am assuming it is ALB closed its connection with Lambda before Lambda responded after 3 seconds. Am I correct? If so, what can I do to prevent this from happening again?
ps. Currently ALB's connection idle timeout is 60 seconds.
